# "Unscrollable" 100vh section snapping to scrollable website content

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have been trying to implement a design where we have a fullscreen header that does not have a scrollbar, but when you try to scroll over the header, the page snaps (100vh) down to the website's content. The content then has a normal scroll.

Same thing should happen when you scroll up - you scroll through the pages content until you bump into the header and then you're taken (100vh) up to the header.

On top of that, I am using scroll based animations inside the website's content, plus I need to be able to scroll to next section and to a specific div inside the website's content on click.

```
<body>

  <div class="header">
    ... 100vh header, does not have a scrollbar, snaps to next section on scroll
  </div>
  <div class="content">
   ... website's content, has scrollbar and scrolls normaly through the content
  </div>

</body>
```

We tried Scrollify and had issues with switching between 100vh section and more than 100vh content but most importantly - each scrollify section is a part of a scrollable website and has a scrollbar.

We also tried what was basically listening for scroll on body if user is on top of the page, then moving 100vh down (and the other way around): https://codepen.io/luciestefkova/full/OGVryw

Comment: How about [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jRPjVz).

Comment: @Shikkediel I think all that is missing is having it animate instead of a hard snap but overall the concept is still the same.

Comment: Yeah, it's just the basics as I wasn't sure what kind of snap OP was aiming at. Animated is likely a nicer user interaction. I have a suspicion that with the address bar on mobile, it'll be tricky to scroll the full initial screen (I recall its size changes when one starts scrolling). It might be an idea to allow overflow (remove the class) at the first `touchstart` and not interfere with scrolling there.

Comment: @Shikkediel That looks quite like what I am trying to do, thank you! I didn't have much time lately to come back to this issue, will do so over the weekend and update once I have a solution.
Also I already have a piece of js to handle my fullscreen components on mobile, so I'll see if I can implement that to make sure the scroll is correct.

Comment: @FarzadA Thank you for you answer below. As for the animation, yes I am aiming for a smooth scroll to the next section, snap was probably not the best way to describe it.

Answer (score 1):

A few things you can do that can achieve this design.

1. Set the height of your content to height: 0 by default.
2. Change your scroll event listener to "wheel" instead. Scroll will never fire if the page has nothing scrollable. Wheel however, you can detect wheel direction and if the direction is down, set the height of your content back to normal (height: unset)
3. Use an animation library to scroll to the start of content container.
4. Add an IntersectionObserver to your content container so that when it leaves the viewport, (basically if the user scrolls back to the top of the page) have the height of the content go back to 0 again so it removes the scrollbar.

Note: you will also need to use touchstart/touchend to detect scroll direction on mobile. Again, scroll won't work without a scrollable window hence why wheel and touch events are required.